# How to get php form data to pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am displaying all the users in the form using php where the data are fetched from db.

When i click on the icon all users data should be show in a pdf.

How should this can be done.

kindly advice.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/421-PHP-Free-PDF-generation-class-without-PDFlib.html#download

works cool and got the perfect output.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [fpdf](http://fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much effort you want to put in, but one way is via [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects). If you're interested, have a look at [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is to use html2pdf class from here:

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples

Answer (score 0):

For info about pdf libraries for PHP visit this stackoverflow link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php

You will find there (as someone else suggested) this is a useful link:
http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples